# Eclipse - how to import recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm using Eclipse & ADT because my laptop is very slow with android studio.
I've tried to use jars from the extras downloaded from the sdk manager and I always get the same error

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

My layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.lifegoals.app.YourGoalsActivity" >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

How can I import the recyclerview library or other support libraries into eclipse, without gradle?

Full stacktrace:

```
    05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.YourGoalsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at com.example.app.YourGoalsActivity.onCreate(YourGoalsActivity.java:14)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     ... 10 more
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     ... 20 more
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):         ... 24 more
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):         ... 23 more
05-20 07:55:27.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1897):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: @TimCastelijns nope. Tried everything from that question.

Comment: That is exactly how it's done though. You may want to include your logcat stacktrace btw

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-v7-recyclerview/issues/1

Comment: I've also added full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Browse to the `sdk/extras/android/support/v7/recyclerview` directory and copy the JAR file to your `libs` folder in your project.

Comment: http://i.snag.gy/ka7hb.jpg , I go the the last version, I have no .jar, i need to extract .aar file, get the classes.jar and impor, but same error..i've tried this already

Comment: @Paul I'm facing the same error. I import classes.jar to libs. But it still doesn't work. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes ,  I was using the wrong folder.  In my case i copied the 'android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar' from  "D:\Android\Android SDK\extras\android\support\v7\recyclerview\libs" and it worked.

Comment: @Paul Thanks. But in my case there is no folder "recycler view" in "extras\android\support\v7". The only place where I can see "recycler view" is in "extras\android\m2repository...".

Comment: Because you must download from the SDK Manager

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project -> properties -> java build Path -> libraries -> add jars. then select the jars you want to add

Comment: I know this, i've already done that...the jar is imported, I get no compile errors about the recyclerview, only runtime exceptions.